# Interactive R graph

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I have an R plot and I'd like the user to be able to click a spot on the graph, and I'd like to know where they clicked. Sort of like a mouse listener. I'm using RStudio. Is this possible in any way? Basically, for a point they click on, I want to display another plot with more details about that point.

Here's what I have:

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(1,2,3,4,5))
x11()
plot(data)

loc <- locator(n=1)
if(loc$x > 2) {
  x11()
  plot(c(1,2,3),c(5,6,7))
}

loc <- locator(n=1)
if(loc$x > 2) {
  x11()
  plot(c(4,5,6),c(5,6,7))
}
```

So, the first plot comes up that has 5 data points. If the user clicks past an x value of 2, then I want to open another plot, which plots the data points you see listed (3 data points). Then, if they close that plot and they click past 2 AGAIN on the original, 5 data point plot, then I want it to open up a new plot with the 3 data points you see in the second if statement.

But it's giving me errors and I/O issues.

Comment: Works fine in a Mac-GUI session running R 2.13.1 and the Mac X11.

Comment: what do you mean Mac-GUI session?

Comment: the 2nd click does not work. only the first does for me. the 2nd click does nothing, even if I close the first 3-data point plot that comes up before I perform the 2nd click on the original plot

Comment: how can I make x11 have the original plot be the active plot?

Comment: you can open and close and set default graphics windows with dev.set, dev.close etc functions.

Comment: @CodeGuy: Simon Urbanek provides a GUI for Macs. http://r.research.att.com/#GUI

Comment: A different avenue: take a look at `iplots` & functions like `iplot`, `iset.selected()`, and more, but you may find that `iplot` alone will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I realize this is not a complete answer but it wouldn't format very well as a comment.) To make a particular device the active device you need to determine its number. After executing your code, I can get my list of devices and set the first X11 device to be current

```
dev.list()
#quartz    X11 quartz    X11    X11 
#     2      3      4      5      6 
dev.set(3)
#X11 
#  3
```

So try this:

```
x11() ; first.ID <- dev.cur()
plot(data)

loc <- locator(n=1)
if(loc$x > 2) {
  x11() ; second.ID <- dev.cur()
  plot(c(1,2,3),c(5,6,7))
}
dev.set(first.ID)
loc <- locator(n=1)
if(loc$x > 2) {
  x11() ; third.ID <- dev.cur()
  plot(c(4,5,6),c(5,6,7))
}
```

On my machine you need to also click on the first graphics window's title to expose it because the Mac Gui does not bring the active device to the foreground.

Comment: Even better (feel free to incorporate this in your answer if you wish). Use `dev.ID <- as.numeric(dev.cur())` just after creating a device to get its ID. You can use `dev.set(dev.ID)` to change device at any time.

Comment: I think the real answer will need to come from someone who has R inside RStudio, since the device interaction seems to be broken or confused in some manner that is not replicable on my machine. But if CodeGuy find our comments point him in the direction of success, I will try to clean up my answer.

Comment: in RStudio `dev.cur()` will always return the same value, no matter which plot you are on, if you use the RStudio device. However, if you use `X11()` to create a new plot, then the `dev.cur`, `dev.set` etc. functions work normally.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in RStudio if you perform the `locator()` call against the built-in plots pane. I think it's calling `locator` against X11 that causes the problems in RStudio. After plotting the X11 detail info, call `dev.set(0)` to make the RStudio plots pane active again.

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(1,2,3,4,5))
plot(data)

loc <- locator(n=1)
if(loc$x > 2) {
        x11()
        plot(c(1,2,3),c(5,6,7))
}

dev.set(0)

loc <- locator(n=1)
if(loc$x > 2) {
        x11()
        plot(c(4,5,6),c(5,6,7))
}
```

(To be honest, I'm not sure why `dev.set(0)` works, would have to check with the developer who wrote the RStudio graphics device.)